# How to enforce vim specific shell history

Tags: vim

Is there any way to have the shell history specific only to a certain instance of vim. For example, observe these sequence of events in both vim shell (`:sh`) and another terminal

```
   Vim (:sh)                  |    Terminal
------------------------------------------------
1  pdflatex foo.tex           |
2                             |   echo hello
3                             |   echo world
```

the command history for both the Terminal and Vim is

```
1  pdflatex foo.tex
2  echo hello
3  echo world
```

Is there any way so the command history for vim is

```
1  pdflatex foo.tex
```

and the Terminal is

```
1  echo hello
2  echo world
```

I ask because I just want to hit the up arrow to execute `pdflatex foo.tex`, I don't want to go through every other command as well. Also, it would be nice if this vim specific history could be saved in the vim session file.

Comment: What is "command history for vim"?

Comment: @wRAR sorry I meant calling the shell from within vim via `:sh`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash stores it's history in `~/.bash_history` by default. This can be changed with the `HISTFILE` environmental variable. So if you want to use a separate history file when you start bash in vim you'll have to set a different value to `HISTFILE`. You can do this by creating a special config file for bash to use when run from within vim. So first make a file `~/.vimbashrc` with this one line in it

```
export HISTFILE=~/.vim_bash_history
```

This will tell bash to use `~/vim_bash_history` as your history file. You could also add more if you want any other specific settings for shells started from vim. Then in your `.vimrc` add the line

```
set shell=/bin/bash\ --init-file\ ~/.vimbashrc
```

The [shell](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27shell%27) setting in vim tells it what command to execute when using `:!` commands and the `:shell` command. The `--init-file` flag tells bash to load the specified config file (it will be loaded after loading your normal `.bashrc`). So now when you run the command `:sh` it will run bash with this config file which will set it to use a different history file.